# Using induction, show ${(1+\sqrt{2})}^{2n}+{(1-\sqrt{2})}^{2n}$ is an even integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I'm having serious difficulties with that task, so it should be nice, if there is someone that can help!

The task says:

> Prove that the number 
>   $${(1+\sqrt{2})}^{2n}+{(1-\sqrt{2})}^{2n}$$ is an even integer for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x,y$ exists such that $x+y$ is an even integer and $xy$ is an integer, then $x^n+y^n$ is always a even integer where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This follows from induction using the fact that $$x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}=(x+y)(x^n+y^n)-xy(x^{n-1}+y^{n-1})$$

To elaborate, you can prove it is true for $1,2$, where $$x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy \equiv (x+y)^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$$ Then show that if we assume that it is true for $n,n+1$, then it follows that it is true for $n+2$.

Comment: This is great, nice and simply explained. +1

Comment: Does this shows that the number is even ?

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis To elaborate, if we show that $x+y$ and $x^2+y^2$ are both even, then proceed with induction in the same manner, we can show that $x^{n}+y^{n}$ is always even.

Comment: Is there any induction proof ? None of your answers have induction though

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis Isn't this induction? Since $x^2+y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ and $x+y \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ this implies that $x^3+y^3 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ from the above formula. In the same way, assume that it is true for $n$, $n+1$. Then it is true for $n+2$. And I don't see why my lack of answers on questions requiring induction is important

Comment: @MXYMXY  I didn't mean your own answers. I mean all of the answers that you and the others gave to me. Is there any classic induction proof ( i.e.,$P(n)\Longrightarrow P(n+1)$ )?

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis None that I know of, that is very simple.

Comment: @MXYMXY I'm a first grader student, I don't know what (mod) is

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis Just enter modulos in google. But generally if we $a \equiv b \pmod p$, this means that $\frac{a-b}{p}$ is an integer.

Comment: @MXYMXY my bad.

Answer (score 4):

This might seem pulled out of hat if you are not familiar with the concept, but the idea is applicable in other similar cases as well, most notably with complex numbers.

Consider the set $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]=\{a+b\sqrt 2\,|\, a,b\in\mathbb Z\}$ and define $\overline{a+b\sqrt 2}=a-b\sqrt 2$. We need couple of facts:

- $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ is multiplicatively closed, i.e. if $x,y\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$, then $x\cdot y\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$. 
  In particular, $x^n\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ for all $x\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$, by induction.
- $(a+b\sqrt 2)+\overline{(a+b\sqrt 2)} = 2a$, i.e. $x+\overline x\in 2\mathbb Z$, for all $x\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$.
- $\overline{x\cdot y} =\overline x\cdot\overline y$ for any $x,y\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$. Therefore, $\overline{x}^n=\overline{x^n}$, by induction, for all $x\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$.

Now, set $x = 1 +\sqrt 2$ and we have $$(1+\sqrt 2)^{2n} + (1-\sqrt 2)^{2n} = x^{2n} + \overline x^{2n} = x^{2n} + \overline {x^{2n}} \in 2\mathbb Z$$

If you've never seen these arguments, it might seem too involved, but actually, you are already familiar with all of this if you know anything about complex numbers. In that case, instead of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$, we have $\mathbb Z[i] = \{a+bi\,|\, a,b\in\mathbb Z\}$ and $\overline z$ is the familiar [complex conjugate](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Complex_conjugate), for which we have $\overline{z\cdot w}=\overline z\cdot\overline w$, and $z+\overline z = 2\operatorname{Re} z\in 2\mathbb Z$.

Hopefully, this will be helpful.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I really don't understand sh**t! I'm a first grader student already !

Comment: (No offense) :)

Comment: Kindly disregard the answer, then :). If you ever take a course in abstract algebra, you will probably encounter this stuff.

Comment: What does conjugation mean? I only know what it means in English grammar...

Comment: @MXYMXY, please see http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Complex_conjugate.

Comment: Ah. So this is $\overline{z}$! I think you should change the sentence third from your last line to $\overline{z}$ $\color{red}{\text{if}}$ to is.

Comment: @MXYMXY, oh, thank you. Well spotted!

Answer (score 3):

Binomial expansion: all the $\sqrt{2}$ terms will cancel and you'll be left with only the powers of two, including $2^0=1$ but that's okay since there's two of them!

EDIT: I relented and actually did the working...

\begin{align*}
(1+\sqrt{2})^{2n} + (1-\sqrt{2})^{2n} &= \sum_{r=0}^{2n}\ ^{2n}C_r \sqrt{2}^{\ r} +\sum_{r=0}^{2n}(-1)^r\ ^{2n}C_r \sqrt{2}^{\ r}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{2n}\ ^{2n}C_r \sqrt{2}^{\ r}+(-1)^r\ ^{2n}C_r \sqrt{2}^{\ r}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{n}2\ ^{2n}C_{2r} \sqrt{2}^{2r}\\
&=2\sum_{r=0}^{n}\ ^{2n}C_{2r} 2^r
\end{align*}

Which is clearly an even integer!

Comment: Can you explain what's that "C"  please ?

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis $^mC_r$ is an alternative notation for $\dbinom{m}{r}$

Comment: @egreg Does $$\left(\sum_{k\leq m}A_{k}\right)+\left(\sum_{k\leq m}B_{k}\right)=\sum_{k\leq m}A_{k}+B_{k}$$ holds ???

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis Yes, where's the problem?

Comment: @egreg I can't understand how did you revealed that "r" at the point: $$\sum_{r=0}^{2n}\ ^{2n}C_{r}\sqrt{2}^{r}r$$

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis Just a typo, well spotted!

Comment: Thus, why did $(-1)^{r}$ disappeared ?

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis It's not my answer! `;-)`

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis looking at the sum on line 2: every odd term cancels and every even term is doubled. The next line is the resulting sum.

Comment: @egreg  That's why I asked Angus Leck ;)

Comment: Ok, but why $\sqrt{2}^{r}\longrightarrow\sqrt{2}^{2r}$ ?

Comment: The sum now only goes up to $n$. Write out the two series (up to 5 or more terms if you have to) to see that this works, what I have done is a subtle change of variables. Perhaps recognising that in line two only even values of $r$ are associated with nonzero terms: put $r = 2k$, then $k$ goes from zero to $n$ and we can just substitute $2k$ into the expression with odd terms removed.

Comment: @AngusLeck thanks for the answer by the way. Is there any induction proof of that ?

Answer (score 3):

If $a_n=pr^n+qs^n$, with $r\ne s$, the sequence $a_n$ satisfies the recurrence relation
$$
a_0=p+q,\qquad a_1=pr+qs,\qquad a_{n+2}-(r+s)a_{n+1}+rsa_n
$$
Indeed,
\begin{align}
a_{n+2}-(r+s)a_{n+1}+rsa_n
&=pr^{n+2}+qs^{n+2}-(r+s)(pr^{n+1}+qs^{n+1})+rs(pr^n+qs^n) \\
&=p(r^{n+2}-r^{n+2}-sr^{n+1}+sr^{n+1}) \\
&\qquad+q(s^{n+2}-rs^{n+1}-s^{n+2}+rs^{n+1})\\
&=0
\end{align}
In our case $p=q=1$, $r=(1+\sqrt{2})^2=3+2\sqrt{2}$, $s=(1-\sqrt{2})^2=3-2\sqrt{2}$; thus $r+s=6$ and $rs=1$.

Therefore the recurrence relation is
$$
a_0=2,\qquad a_1=6, \qquad a_{n+2}-6a_{n+1}+a_n=0
$$
Since $a_0$ and $a_1$ are even (base of the induction), if we assume $a_k$ even for every $k$ with $0\le k<n+2$, then
$$
a_{n+2}=6a_{n+1}-a_n
$$
is even too.

---

A similar strategy is considering $b_n=(1+\sqrt{2})^n+(1-\sqrt{2})^n$. The recurrence relation is
$$
b_0=2,\qquad b_1=2,\qquad b_{n+2}-2b_{n+1}-b_n=0
$$
We want to see that $b_{2n}$ is even; the statement is true for $n=0$. Suppose $b_{2n}$ is even; then
$$
b_{2n+2}=2b_{n+1}+b_n
$$
is even as well.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your reply!